# Listbox display differs on Windows vs Mac

Tags: excel, vba, windows, macos, listbox

I'm creating a small Excel app that will be used by both Windows and Mac users, thus I'm limited to the non-ActiveX form controls.  Both Windows and the Mac are using recent versions of Excel.

If I create a ListBox form control on either platform, the listbox does not behave properly on the other platform.

To recreate the problem, I created a worksheet on Windows with only a Listbox with a simple input range listing values of 1 to 10.  Works as expected in Windows.  When opened on the Mac, the items in the Listbox appear bunched together without the proper spacing.  When you click on the '5' in the list, the '3' is selected and the problem gets more pronounced as you move down the list.
The spacing problem happens in reverse if you develop on the Mac and open on Windows (too much space between items).

On both platforms, manually resizing the listbox fixes the problem.  However, I can't rely on end-users to do that given that there may be a large number of end-users.

I've tried some VBA solutions to try to fix the problem programmatically including using Height, Width, and Visible properties without success.

Comment: Yes these are some problems you will face between MAC and WIN. AFAIK, and I could be wrong, there is no remedy for this. Have you considered using Data Validation List instead of Listbox?

Comment: The only way I can think of that could work is creating the boxes on-the-fly by code. So eg using the *workbook open* event to delete the old ones and create new ones by code. Worth to give it a try.

Comment: I think I found a workable solution.  I turned on the macro recorder while manually resizing the listbox.  It gave me this line which seems to work when placed properly within the VBA code:
   ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 3").ScaleWidth 1.01, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft